# Apache default script, dosnt show name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So the question is rather simply, if you for instance call a site www.example.com then the apache server will call the default script usually index.htm or index.php etc. However, the script is not displayed in the URL bar (i.e. www.example.com/index.php), but rather just example.com.
This wouldnt usually be a problem but Im working on a parameterless URL for SEO (seach engine optimisation). Thus a link on the page such as href="contact" will call example.com/contact rather than example.com/index/contact (index doing the clever stuff, note php extention is hidden).

My idea is to force Apache to display the default script name, anyone know how to do that? Otherwise Im open for suggestions. (Preferably would like to avoid mod_rewrite in .htaccess)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4 - Just use `<base href="/index/" />` in your HTML.

Comment: I would have to use absolute paths for JS, CSS and images right?

Comment: Yes. You can as well also use a separate host for static content, like `static.example.net`.